# Disable browser launch in protractor to test REST services

Tags: protractor

I am testing REST services using PROTRACTOR-HTTP-CLIENT tool in my protractor framework. The same framework also tests the UI application. I have different config file for UI and API test.

But my problem is when I am testing the REST services the chrome browser is launching which has no use.I can use headless chrome but I want to completely disable the browser launch.

Is there any way to disable the browser launch when testing the rest services.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this will be achievable. The webdriver session is triggered during one of the automated hook stages during Protractors initialization, likely the onPrepare hook. This hook functionality will always be executed and there is no ability to override it before it takes place.

What you could do is call `browser.quit()` at the start of your tests to end the session but as far as I know there is no way to stop it from initializing.

Comment: Yes even I didn't find anything to disable the browser, anyway thank you for your response

Answer (score 0):

I have same setup in my project with typescript. For Api tests I have a separate jasmine.json file and npm script "jasmine-ts --config=jasmine.json". This should help you avoid initializing browser and runs only api tests. Basically instead of using protractor to run tests, running tests directly using jasmine framework.
this is how my jasmine.json file looks:

```
{
    "spec_dir": "specs",
  
    "spec_files": [
      "api/*[sS]pec.ts"
    ],
  
    "helpers": [
      "init.ts"
    ],
  
    "stopSpecOnExpectationFailure": false,
  
    "random": false
  }
```